# Advanced set for 5.5 years old

Tags: sets

My son had great success building a lot of Lego models, including complex sets, such as the [Family house set](http://brickset.com/sets/31012-1/Family-House).
And I want to meet him with an advanced model, that includes some gears and more functional.

I thought about 3 models, all of them are a little old but I really love them and I don't know which one to buy. The models are [5893](http://brickset.com/sets/5893-1/Off-Road-Power), [4993](http://brickset.com/sets/4993-1/Cool-Convertible) and [5767](http://brickset.com/sets/5767-1/Cool-Cruiser).

I'll be glad to receive an advice, which set is most recommended, considering my son's age (5.5) and props of each set.

I'm open to new suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to suggest that unless you're getting these sets at their retail price, don't bother getting any of these for a 5 year old. Instead, just get a current set, such as [31017 Sunset Speedster](http://shop.lego.com/en-CA/Sunset-Speeder-31017), which is still available at its regular price. Or check out the line of [Speed Champions](http://shop.lego.com/en-CA/Speed-Champions-ByTheme).

My reasoning is that a small child does not care about the vintage of a set and is not completing a collection, so any particular set is equivalent to any other. The sports car model is one that Lego refreshes every so often and there is almost always one available for sale, and you can usually get it at a discount. But all retired sets increase in price on the secondary market and I'd say you are getting zero value for your extra money if you hand this set to a child. They will love the set but not care at all if it's rare or hard to find.

As for how age-appropriate such a set is, it depends on the child. The Creator sets are fairly easy to build, usually. My 5 year old has little difficulty building them, though he has a fair amount of Lego experience. If your son has already built several models, these sets should be fine, even if the ages say 7 or 8 and up. I find that Lego's age recommendations are too conservative for my household, but YMMV.

Addressing your point about wanting to build with gears, etc. Most Creator models have minimal gears involved. Certainly the sports cars do not have working steering or anything like that. Creator sets almost never feature that sort of functionality except on the largest models. When there are moving parts, they are typically just hinged.

If you want something that features actual gears, steering, etc, you need to peruse the Technic line. Most of that is fairly complex. It's aimed at an older audience and I'd wager your 5 year old isn't ready for it - at least, mine wouldn't be. If Technic is too complicated, you might try one of these:

[Fairground Mixer](http://shop.lego.com/en-CA/Fairground-Mixer-10244)

[Ferris Wheel](http://shop.lego.com/en-CA/Ferris-Wheel-10247)

They are large models, fairly expensive, that feature both brick-built devices and mechanical movements. Both can be motorized by adding a motor (sold separately). Both are large sets that display well, but feature lots of play features. The Mixer, especially, is very cleverly constructed. I'd say both are too advanced for a 5 year old, but with a parent's help, and some patience, they should be possible.

Comment: Thank you very much ! but the two models seems for me too much easy and the latest models are really very expensive...

Comment: The car models I suggested are of the same difficulty add the ones you asked about. They should also be comparable prices. The two Creator expert fairground rides are expensive but definitely not easy. However, the older sets are usually much more expensive than the later sets. If you can find them at a good price, they'll do just fine. But there is little technical difference between the creator car models on a yearly basis. They just refresh the model with new colors or updated parts.

Comment: @ Nr, Shiny - Thank you very much! I'll take one of them

Answer (score 1):

The 4993 seems to be just a static display mode with no gears or functionality apart from the opening hood, doors and roof.

The 5893 in contrast has working steering, suspension, winch, etc. These provide playing and learning possibilities.

The 5671 has some odd colors and a working steering wheel, but nothing more than this.

To sum it up, if I were you, I'd buy the 5893. Disclaimer: I don't own any of these sets, I only saw them online. I might be mistaken about what I wrote.

Comment: Thank you very much ! btw, maybe you have an idea of another set? Thanks again!!

Comment: It's been quite a long time since either myself or a close relative of mine was 5.5 years old, so I don't really know what are his interests and skills. In my opinion, LEGO enthusiasts can be grouped in three categories: Builders, Players, Collectors. These might overlap though. I seriously doubt your son would be a collector (as in keeping sets in mint condition, behind glass), so that leaves builder (builds, expands, invents, alters models) and player (roleplaying with figures and models). These two tend to enjoy different sets, but a good compromise surely can be found.

Answer (score 1):

It's my old question but want to share with "new" lego I found, called **Kluntz Lego**.

The Kluntz Lego is for complex structures, gears, etc.

Here is an [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9jl89A9vLvY).